# Why files created by Kaleidoscope App are in quarantine?

Tags: macos, security, extended-attributes

I like to use [Kaleidoscope](http://www.kaleidoscopeapp.com) (v 2.1.0 - build 133.01 under Mac OS X 10.8.5) to compare 2 directories.

But, when I create files by copying them from a directory to another using Kaleidoscope, (e.g., when a file is missing in one of the two directories), the file is always created with an [extended attribute](https://serverfault.com/q/403963/58782) `com.apple.quarantine`!

**An exemple:**

*creation of 2 directories to compare, with a file in the first:*

```
$ mkdir rep1
$ mkdir rep2
$ echo test > rep1/test.txt
```

*checking attributes:*

```
$ ls -lah rep1
total 8
drwxr-xr-x  3 user staff   102B 26 jui 20:52 .
drwxr-xr-x  7 user staff   238B 26 jui 20:51 ..
-rw-r--r--  1 user staff     5B 26 jui 20:52 test.txt
$ ls -lah rep2
total 0
drwxr-xr-x  2 user staff    68B 26 jui 20:52 .
drwxr-xr-x  7 user staff   238B 26 jui 20:51 ..
```

*Selection of the file to copy it with Kaleidoscope:*

[image: Selection of a file to copy it]

*Copy operation:*

[image: Copy operation]

*result of the operation on the attributes:*

```
$ ls -lah rep1
total 8
drwxr-xr-x  3 user staff   102B 26 jui 20:52 .
drwxr-xr-x  7 user staff   238B 26 jui 20:51 ..
-rw-r--r--  1 user staff     5B 26 jui 20:52 test.txt
$ ls -lah rep2
total 8
drwxr-xr-x  3 user staff   102B 26 jui 20:55 .
drwxr-xr-x  7 user staff   238B 26 jui 20:51 ..
-rw-r--r--@ 1 user staff     5B 26 jui 20:52 test.txt
```

As you can see, an `@` was added to the attributes of `test.txt` in `rep2`, and with more investigation, it's easy to see that it's a `com.apple.quarantine` created because of Kaleidoscope:

```
$ xattr rep2/test.txt
com.apple.quarantine
$ xattr -p com.apple.quarantine rep2/test.txt 
0002;53ac6c96;Kaleidoscope;
```

---

I now it's easy to get rid of it with `xattr -r com.apple.quarantine [file]` on a file or `xattr -dr com.apple.quarantine [directory]` on a directory, but I find this very annoying!

**Here are my questions:**

- Why, an extended attribute is added on my files each times they are created through Kaleidoscope (new Mac OS security for non-sandboxed apps, or anything else…)?
- Is it possible to avoid this comportment, and to create files with Kaleidoscope without having a quarantine on each files?

Thanks a lot for your help and your time!

**[EDIT]**

Tanks to [konqui](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/62463/konqui), I've now a solution to completely disable the files quarantined, but I'm looking for a more specific solution, only for Kaleidoscope… Is this possible?

And is there any proof about our theories about thoses quarantine, or are they due by something else that the new security for non-sandbexed app?

Thanks a lot for your help, and thank you [konqui](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/62463/konqui) for what you've already done.

Comment: my thoughts go in the same direction as yours (new Mac OS security for non-sandboxed apps) - for your sdcond question it will be the best approach to write an email to the developers of kaleidoscope -> kaleidoscope@blackpixel.com?subject=Kaleidoscope%20Feedback

Comment: If this is due to the new Mac OS's Security for non-sandboxed app, I'll prefer a solution non-specific to Kaleidoscope, because it's not the only app that I have who isn't sandboxed… Nobody can give a clue about this problem?

Answer (score 2):

The system's quarantine feature is a good security measure so I would not recommend this to everyone, but if you are confident in the files you download and run on your system then one option is to disable quarantining altogether. To do this, open the Terminal and run the following command, then reboot the system:

```
defaults write com.apple.LaunchServices LSQuarantine -bool NO
```

source: http://www.cnet.com/news/workarounds-for-quarantine-bug-in-os-x-lion/

Comment: Thank for the tips (+1 for you), but is there any solution to disable quarantine JUST for Kaleidoscope?

Comment: maybe i can find out something more about it later this week by now i don't know if there is a solution just for Kaleidoscope

Comment: Thank you. I've understand about your link that its a problem for sandboxed App, but kaleidoscope isn't sandboxed…